# Set page scroll top using css not jquery

Tags: css

I am working on multi view in asp web form.
For each view scroll position is not varying.It remains same that should not happens.

```
$('body').scrollTop(0);
```

is this possible with css

Comment: i don't think so, css are just styles to make the page better look

Answer (score 1):

No. This is not possible with just using css. Because css doesn't accept expression script.